# Lubuntu 16.04 32 bit: Installing Steam

Tags: lubuntu, steam

I'm a newbie to Linux and Ubuntu in general.  I've been doing baby steps in trying to figure it all out.  But there's one thing I'd like to figure out something that's been bothering me as a gamer: Installing Steam.  I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this.

I've tried looking this stuff up, but my google-fu and ubuntu command line wizard skills are quite lacking.  Your help would very much be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

press "CTRL ALT T" together to open up a terminal.  Then type in

```
sudo apt-get install steam
```

Comment: This is what I got:  Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package steam

Comment: try running    sudo apt-get update   then    sudo apt-get install steam

Answer (score 0):

Go to the [Steam homepage](http://store.steampowered.com/about/) and click the big green install button.  It will download the .deb file you need.  Open your Downloads folder, right-click the steam_latest.deb, and select Gdebi Package Installer from the menu.  Click Install Package on the next box that opens.  Type in your password when it asks.  You are done.

Comment: There's an error that says 'Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: curl'

Comment: Where does this install to? This is the problem I'm having, or don't understand, is where exactly it is installing? Looking around my file system, it appears nothing actually installs when going via Steam website

Comment: @bananabrann that procedure installs the `steam-launcher` package which installs files in `/usr/bin/steam`, `/usr/bin/steamdeps`, `/usr/lib/steam`, etc, etc